# How to set both height of vertical 'b-tabs' navigation part and content part same (based on the content part)

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I want to get `max-height` value from somewhere else (eg: vue data:) and apply it on the `b-tabs` navigation part. I know we can create a css class and set it to `nav-class` to change the style at navigation part, but I failed to update the style that I set to the nav-class.

I want to set the `b-tabs` content height to the navigation part height.

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <b-row class="wrap" ref="wrap">
      <b-tabs vertical content-class="mt-3">
        <b-tab v-for="category in categories" v-bind:title="category.name" :key="category.id">
          {{ category.name }} I want to set this part height to the leftnigation panel so that the left side height is the same as the right side
        </b-tab>
        <b-tab>
          Content
        </b-tab>
      </b-tabs>
    </b-row>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    categories: [
      { name: "1" },
      { name: "2" },
      { name: "3" },
      { name: "3" },
      { name: "3" },
      { name: "3" },
      { name: "3" },
      { name: "3" },
      { name: "3" },
      { name: "3" },
      { name: "3" },
      { name: "3" }
    ]
  }
})
```

```
.wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.nav-tabs {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

I want the left panel height same as the right panel height.

Comment: example [link](https://jsfiddle.net/cfsL7buj/5/)

Comment: If you use pills & card on b-tabs as `<b-tabs pills card vertical>`, it takes the max-height

Comment: I want overwrite the left side max-height and make it same as the right side
Now, if left side max-height is more than the right side, the right side height will follow the left, i want the left side follow the right side, **always**

Comment: Or maybe something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ksneo6jd/ ?

Comment: i want left to match the right, not the opposite

Answer (score -2):

here is the example [solution](http://nadirprogramlar.blogspot.com/2019/06/bootstrap-41-same-height-nav-tab-pane.html).

Comment: its not related to the op